# In latex, how to add a header in the document class “deedy-resume”?

Tags: templates, cv, deedy-resume

This template titled "Deedy-resume" is available here; https://www.overleaf.com/3391198rtbjch#/9562876/

I intend to add a certain text content on the top right corner of the page. Can anyone please suggest the necessary changes in the class file and tex file to accommodate a document header?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe you can make the example in your link a bit more minimal (the entire 270 lines are probably not needed to show the problem), if you strip down your code, it is better to post the resulting [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) here instead of linking to an external site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the features of package `textpos` like this:

```
\begin{textblock}{30}(80,1)
    certain text content
\end{textblock}
```

which gves us:

[image: praneetCvHeader]